# R Manipulate data frame with multiple information in columns

Tags: r, reshape2, melt

How can I reshape this dataframe regarding the multiple information of the columns 2:7 (day_rep), obtaining this new "datlong" dataframe with the coumns:
"trat" "day" "rep" "value"

```
dat <- read.table(header=T, text='
trat    5_1 5_2 6_1 6_2 7_1 7_2
control 0   0   0   0   12  66
control 0   0   0   0   14  76
control 0   0   0   0   18  78
control 0   0   0   0   16  74
control 0   0   0   0   20  76
urea    0   0   0   12  42  88
urea    0   0   0   8   34  76
urea    0   0   0   6   28  68
urea    0   0   0   4   40  60
urea    0   0   0   10  46  78
')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gather/separate` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(dat, dayrep, value, -trat) %>% 
        separate(dayrep, into=c("day", "rep")) %>%
        head()
#     trat day rep value
#1 control   5   1     0
#2 control   5   1     0
#3 control   5   1     0
#4 control   5   1     0
#5 control   5   1     0
#6    urea   5   1     0
```